# Python sports XML parsing

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to print the attributes from each of the pro teams in the following XML file http://api.cbssports.com/fantasy/pro-teams/?version=3.0&SPORT=basketball

For now I am just trying to display the nicknames but that's not even working

Heres my code

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

request = Request('http://api.cbssports.com/fantasy/pro-teams?version=3.0&SPORT=basketball')

try:
    response = urlopen(request)
    tree = ET.parse(response)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for team in root.findall('pro_team'):
      nickname = team.get('nickname')
      print nickname
except URLError, e:
print 'error:', e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
root.findall('.//pro_team')
```

instead of `root.findall('pro_team')` to find all `<pro_team>` elements under `root`. `root.findall('pro_team')` returns an empty list because there is no `<pro_team>` element which is a *direct child* of `root`.

Also, `team.get` is used to retrieve *attributes* of the `team`. The nickname is
not an attribute<sup>1</sup>; it is a child element. So use `team.find('nickname')` instead.

---

<sup>1</sup>If nickname were an attribute, the XML would look like

```
<pro_team nickname="Spurs">...</pro_team>
```

instead of

```
<pro_team><nickname>Spurs</nickname></pro_team>
```

---

```
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://api.cbssports.com/fantasy/pro-teams?version=3.0&SPORT=basketball'
request = urllib2.Request(url)

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    tree = ET.parse(response)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for team in root.findall('.//pro_team'):
        nickname = team.find('nickname').text
        print nickname
except URLError, e:
    print 'error:', e
```